How to work with complex data type in Pyspark
I am having below issue when I have one dataframe and it is having one column name is attribute and attribute type is
|-- attributes: string (nullable = true)
in that column i am having values like below
[
    {'name': 'sfcc.created_by', 'type': 'STRING', 'value': 'DummyUser'},
    {'name': 'shippingLines', 'type': 'JSON', 'value': {'code': 'DUMMYCODE', 'price': '0', 'discountedPrice': '0'}},
    {'name': 'sourceChannel', 'type': 'STRING', 'value': 'dummyOS'},
    {'name': 'leaveAtDoor', 'type': 'BOOLEAN', 'value': False},
    {'name': 'actualCreateDate', 'type': 'STRING', 'value': '2024-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'},
    {'name': 'orderCompleteDate', 'type': 'STRING', 'value': '2024-01-02T00:00:00.000Z'},
    {'name': 'sfcc.order_date', 'type': 'STRING', 'value': '2024-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'},
    {'name': 'orderSuccessfullyCreatedInSAP', 'type': 'BOOLEAN', 'value': True},
    {'name': 'splitPayments', 'type': 'JSON', 'value': [{'price': '100', 'gateway': 'DUMMYGATEWAY', 'paymentGatewayName': 'DUMMY_CARD'}]},
    {'name': 'sfcc.customer_locale', 'type': 'STRING', 'value': 'en_US'},
    {'name': 'customerId', 'type': 'STRING', 'value': '000DummyID0000'},
    {'name': 'financialStatus', 'type': 'STRING', 'value': 'DUMMYSTATUS'},
    {'name': 'addressLine1', 'type': 'STRING', 'value': 'Dummy Street 1'},
    {'name': 'sourceLocation', 'type': 'STRING', 'value': 'DUMMYWEBSITE'},
    {'name': 'addressLine2', 'type': 'STRING', 'value': 'Dummy Street 2'},
    {'name': 'subtotalPrice', 'type': 'STRING', 'value': '100'},
    {'name': 'carrierId', 'type': 'STRING', 'value': 'DummyCarrier'},
    {'name': 'isCancelable', 'type': 'BOOLEAN', 'value': False},
    {'name': 'consignments', 'type': 'JSON', 'value': ['0000-0000-0000-0000']},
    {'name': 'sfcc.shipments', 'type': 'JSON', 'value': {'shipments': [{'items': [{'skuRef': '0000000000', 'quantity': 1}], 'isGift': False, 'shipmentId': '00000000', 'giftMessage': None, 'shippingAddress': {'area': 'Dummy Area', 'city': 'Dummy City', 'name': 'John Doe', 'phone': '+00000000000', 'street': 'Dummy Street', 'country': 'XX', 'lastName': 'Doe', 'postcode': '00000', 'firstName': 'John'}, 'shippingMethodRef': 'XXX000'}]}}
]


I want to get all result in separate columns like
sfcc.created_by  shippingLines
DummyUser        {'code': 'DUMMYCODE', 'price': '0', 'discountedPrice': '0'}



You have different data type for the 'value' column. Is this how the actual data appears?

yes this is the data

this is in single column

from pyspark.sql.functions import (
    regexp_replace,
    from_json,
    schema_of_json,
    map_from_entries,
    col,
    expr,
    explode,
)

# Create the dataframe.

data = [
    (
        """[{"name": "sfcc.created_by", "type": "STRING", "value": "XXXXX"},
 {'name': 'shippingLines', 'type': 'JSON', 'value': {'code': 'XXXXX', 'price': '0', 'discountedPrice': '0'}}, 
 {'name': 'sourceChannel', 'type': 'STRING', 'value': 'XXXXX'}, 
 {'name': 'leaveAtDoor', 'type': 'BOOLEAN', 'value': False}, 
 {'name': 'actualCreateDate', 'type': 'STRING', 'value': '2020-04-13T14:02:21.529Z'}, 
 {'name': 'orderCompleteDate', 'type': 'STRING', 'value': '2020-04-15T11:16:17.086Z'}, 
 {'name': 'sfcc.order_date', 'type': 'STRING', 'value': '2020-04-13T14:01:36.000Z'}, 
 {'name': 'orderSuccessfullyCreatedInSAP', 'type': 'BOOLEAN', 'value': True},
 {'name': 'splitPayments', 'type': 'JSON', 'value': [{'price': 'XXXXX', 'gateway': 'XXXXX', 'paymentGatewayName': 'XXXXX'}]}, 
 {'name': 'sfcc.customer_locale', 'type': 'STRING', 'value': 'XXXXX'}, 
 {'name': 'customerId', 'type': 'STRING', 'value': 'XXXXX'}, 
 {'name': 'financialStatus', 'type': 'STRING', 'value': 'XXXXX'},
 {'name': 'addressLine1', 'type': 'STRING', 'value': 'XXXXX'}, 
 {'name': 'sourceLocation', 'type': 'STRING', 'value': 'XXXXX'}, 
 {'name': 'addressLine2', 'type': 'STRING', 'value': 'XXXXX'},
 {'name': 'subtotalPrice', 'type': 'STRING', 'value': 'XXXXX'}, 
 {'name': 'carrierId', 'type': 'STRING', 'value': 'XXXXX'}, 
 {'name': 'isCancelable', 'type': 'BOOLEAN', 'value': False}, 
 {'name': 'consignments', 'type': 'JSON', 'value': ['XXXXX']},
 {'name': 'sfcc.shipments', 'type': 'JSON', 'value': {'shipments': [{'items': [{'skuRef': 'XXXXX', 'quantity': 1}], 'isGift': False, 'shipmentId': 'XXXXX', 'giftMessage': None, 'shippingAddress': {'area': 'Other', 'city': 'XXXXX', 'name': 'XXXXX', 'phone': '+910000000', 'street': 'XXXXX', 'country': 'XXXXX', 'lastName': 'XXXXX', 'postcode': None, 'firstName': 'XXXXX'}, 'shippingMethodRef': 'XXXXX'}]}}    
 ]
""",
    ),
(
        """[{"name": "sfcc.created_by", "type": "STRING", "value": "AAAAA"},
 {'name': 'shippingLines', 'type': 'JSON', 'value': {'code': 'BBBBB', 'price': '0', 'discountedPrice': '0'}}, 
 {'name': 'sourceChannel', 'type': 'STRING', 'value': 'CCCC'}, 
 {'name': 'leaveAtDoor', 'type': 'BOOLEAN', 'value': False}, 
 {'name': 'actualCreateDate', 'type': 'STRING', 'value': '2020-04-13T14:02:21.529Z'}
 ]
""",
    )    
]
columns = ["attributes"]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=columns)

EDIT: Sample data is not a valid JSON, hence it must be cleaned up first. The rest of the code works as is.
df = (
    df.withColumn("attributes", regexp_replace("attributes", "False", "false"))
      .withColumn("attributes", regexp_replace("attributes", "True", "true"))
      .withColumn("attributes", regexp_replace("attributes", "None", "null"))
)

Assuming that your data is in the dataframe df, you can parse the data into a Map column:
# Parse the string data as a JSON and then into a MAP type.
df = (
    df.withColumn(
        "attributes",
        from_json(
            col("attributes"), schema_of_json(df.select(col("attributes")).first()[0])
        ),
    )
    .withColumn(
        "attributes", expr("transform(attributes, x -> struct(x.name, x.value))")
    )
    .withColumn("attributes", map_from_entries("attributes"))
)

Once you have the data in a Map type column, you can extract the keys and then select the keys as individual columns:
# Extract all possible keys from the dataframe.
keys = (
    df.select(explode("attributes"))
    .select("key")
    .distinct()
    .rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x)
    .collect()
)

# Create the desired dataframe.
df = df.select(*[col("attributes").getItem(k).alias(k) for k in keys])
df.show()

Result:
+--------------------+------------+---------+--------------------+-------------+-----------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+----------+---------------+--------------------+-------------+------------+-----------+------------+
|sfcc.customer_locale|isCancelable|carrierId|   orderCompleteDate|subtotalPrice|orderSuccessfullyCreatedInSAP|    actualCreateDate|     sfcc.order_date|       splitPayments|consignments|financialStatus|sourceLocation|      sfcc.shipments|customerId|sfcc.created_by|       shippingLines|sourceChannel|addressLine2|leaveAtDoor|addressLine1|
+--------------------+------------+---------+--------------------+-------------+-----------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+----------+---------------+--------------------+-------------+------------+-----------+------------+
|               XXXXX|       false|    XXXXX|2020-04-15T11:16:...|        XXXXX|                         true|2020-04-13T14:02:...|2020-04-13T14:01:...|[{"price":"XXXXX"...|   ["XXXXX"]|          XXXXX|         XXXXX|{"shipments":[{"i...|     XXXXX|          XXXXX|{"code":"XXXXX","...|        XXXXX|       XXXXX|      false|       XXXXX|
|                null|        null|     null|                null|         null|                         null|2020-04-13T14:02:...|                null|                null|        null|           null|          null|                null|      null|          AAAAA|{"code":"BBBBB","...|         CCCC|        null|      false|        null|
+--------------------+------------+---------+--------------------+-------------+-----------------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+------------+---------------+--------------+--------------------+----------+---------------+--------------------+-------------+------------+-----------+------------+



wow, this is amazing i was even not able to think that ,thanks

but this is not working in my databricks system

What is the error you're getting? Please post some reproducible code and sample data.

[NOT_COLUMN_OR_STR] Argument json should be a Column or str, got NoneType.
File , line 7
1 from pyspark.sql.functions import *
3 df = (
4     newdata.withColumn(
5         "attributes",
eys])

Your snippet doesn't say anything about the actual problem, but I'm guessing it is because your data isn't really a valid JSON.  Updated my answer accordingly.

[JVM_ATTRIBUTE_NOT_SUPPORTED] Attribute rdd is not supported in Spark Connect as it depends on the JVM. If you need to use this attribute, do not use Spark Connect when creating your session. Visit https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-getting-started.html#starting-point-sparksession for creating regular Spark Session in detail.

yes yes it is working as expected , thanks again,you are awesome

Using the col.explode function would be a good place to start.  You may have to call it several times in order to unpack these values. I cannot tell how many layers of nesting your data has.
But, in pyspark, it should look something like this:
attributes = df.select(explode(df.attributes))
shippingLines = attributes.select(explode(attributes.shippingLines))

